# How to post from windows phone 8.1 to PHP Script

Tags: php, windows-phone-8

I am getting this error while post from a Windows Phone 8.1 to a PHP Script

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072EFD

The post from a console app to the PHP script works fine, but something is different for the Windows Phone.

In the console app I used  `ASCIIEncoding` but I could not find it in Windows Phone so I am using `HttpClient`. I am running Apache on WAMP.

```
static HttpClient clientOb = new HttpClient();
static Uri uri = new Uri("http://192.168.1.4/sign_in.php");
static Dictionary<string, string> pairs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
   public async void webReq()
   {
       try
       {
           pairs.Add("email", "1");
           pairs.Add("password", "1");
           await AsyncTask();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
           txtOut.Text = ex.Message;
       }

   }
   static async Task AsyncTask()
   {

       try
       {
           HttpFormUrlEncodedContent formContent = new    HttpFormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);
           HttpResponseMessage response = await clientOb.PostAsync(uri, formContent);
           if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
           {
               var dialog = new MessageDialog(response.Content.ToString());
               await dialog.ShowAsync();
               Debug.WriteLine(dialog);
               Debug.WriteLine("dialog");
           }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);

       }
```

Comment: `0x80072efd` means "A connection with the server could not be established". Most likely your network settings/firewall/equipment doesn't allow your phone to connect to the server.

Comment: is there a way I can allow it to connect to the server? is it a setting in visual studio or wamp pc it self?

Comment: Thank you VolKerk... I turned off my Firewall and its working

Comment: I'd rather define a rule allowing this kind of traffic instead of turning off the firewall completely.

Comment: ok ill look into it thanks... The most important thing is that I know what is causing the error and I want to thank you